# Check if multiple cookies exist

Tags: javascript, cookies

I want to check if 2 cookies are exist and then trigger a click.

Following code is what i did for checking one cookie:

```
var firstRun = getCookie('username');
    if (firstRun == "") {
        $(".fancybox").trigger( "click" );
    }
```

I'd like to check if `username` and `temp` cookies are exist, how can i implement it?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine two conditions into your `if` statement:

```
if (getCookie('username') && getCookie('temp')) {
    $(".fancybox").trigger( "click" );
}
```

This checks if both cookies exist. You can create any combination of logic you need with the two conditions and the intervening operator.